# Print same output as python console in flask rendered HTML

Tags: python, html, flask, ssh, paramiko

I have a python script that prints console output from a network device and its working great, I get an output like this:[Python Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtxEC.png)

Now I'm trying to run it from a web server with Flask, and It's working great except that the output in the rendered HTML template is one string like this:

```
display mac-address 44FB-5ABC-9788
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
MAC Address VLAN/VSI/BD Learned-From Type 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
44fb-5abc-9788 1579/-/- Eth-Trunk1 amic
------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
Total items displayed = 1
```

What I want is the same output in the HTML page as python console, here is what I have with flask:

```
@app.route('/result',methods = ['POST', 'GET']) 
def result():    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        hw_input = str(request.form.get("hw"))
        commandinput = str(request.form.get("command"))
        user = 'user'
        passv = 'pass'
        passg = 'password'
        user_prompt = '.*name:'
        pass_prompt =  '.*assword:'
        hw_prompt = '.*>'
        hw_connect = 'telnet ' + hw_input

        ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient() 
        ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh_client.connect(hostname='host', username=user, password=passv)

        interact = SSHClientInteraction(ssh_client, timeout=10, display=False)
        interact.send(hw_connect)
        interact.expect(user_prompt)
        interact.send(user)
        interact.expect(pass_prompt)
        interact.send(passg)
        interact.expect(hw_prompt)
        interact.send(commandinput)
        interact.expect(hw_prompt)
        output = interact.current_output_clean
        return render_template("result.html",result = output)
```

Comment: put it in a `<pre>` tag?

Comment: Can you post html code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much!! I was missing `<pre>` tag in result.html